# template template parameter for stl containers behaving different from custom template class

Tags: c++, templates, stl, template-templates

I have the following struct and function

```
template <class T> struct C {};

template <template <class S> class T, class U> void f() { T<U> tu; }
```

when templating `f()` with `C` I do not get an error, when templating it with say `std::vector` I do.

```
int main() {
  f<C, int>();
}
```

yields no errors

```
int main() {
    f<std::vector, int>();
}
```

yields

```
error: no matching function for call to 'f'
f<std::vector, int>();
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'T'
template <template <class S> class T, class U> void f() { T<U> tu; }
```

What is the difference between `C` and `std::vector` here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) has two template parameters, not one (`T` and `Allocator`).

You can either change your `f` template to accept two template parameters (or a variadic pack):

```
template <template <class...> class T, class U> void f() { T<U> tu; }
```

or you can alias `vector` to a 1-parameter template:

```
template<typename T>
using vec = std::vector<T>;
```

Answer (score 2):

difference is that vector has two template parameters, not one. To fix this you may use

```
template <template <class... S> class T, class U> void f() { T<U> tu; }
```